# CSS how to fill the entire width?

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-float

i already goggle but still don't know what to do

i have 3 div

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="center"> <h1>center</h1> </div>
        <div id="right"> <h1>right</h1> </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

what i try to accomplish

- div id=center is auto fill the width
- div id=right is in right position of the div id=center,  width=200px;

what i try so far

```
#center{
    background-color: green;
        float: left;
        overflow: auto;
}

#right{
    background-color: red;
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
}
```

How to make div id=center fill the entire width with another div (div id=right) in right position of it

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iliketo/FNmVN/)

forgive my english

Comment: `#center { width: 80%; } #right{ width: 20%; max-width: 200px;} ` this should get you close enough I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this from [here](http://web-profile.com.ua/css/dev/css-width-100prc-minus-100px/) and learnt a new/useful one.

The following solution will not affect your dom in making changes.

```
#center{
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px);
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FNmVN/4/)

Comment: Keep in mind that calc isn't supported on IE8 and below, as well as all of android. Sadly, IE8 is still fairly prominent in usage.

Answer (score 5):

If you need a pure CSS Solution, than consider altering your DOM

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FNmVN/1/)

First of all, remove `float: left;` property from `#center`, and than I've added `width: auto;` and `overflow: hidden;` properties which will make the columns independent.

Reference Code :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="center"></div>
</div>

#container {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#center {
    background-color: green;
    width: auto;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#right {
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
    height: 20px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: i need css, your demo is what i try to accomplish, but i can't alter the DOM, because this css will become template later

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't work that way - you need to nest the 'right' div inside of the 'center' div:

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="center">
      <h1>center</h1> 
      <div id="right">
        <h1>right</h1> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Then make the `h1` display inline:

```
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
#center {
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#right {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}
```

[Here's an updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/FNmVN/2/)

Comment: your demo is what i try to accomplish, but i need css solution without changing the DOM

Comment: Mr Alien's answer is actually a better DOM altering solution anyway. I'll see if I can come up with a CSS only solution.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this separate since the other one may be useful to someone in the future. Here's the only CSS only solution I could come up with, but there's a caveat: you have to use percentage based widths on both divs:

```
#center {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
}

#right {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
```

20% should be close to what you need on the smaller div, and you can use media queries if necessary to keep it from being too wide on larger screens.

[Here's an updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/FNmVN/3/)

Comment: thanks, but can't use percentage for the best answer. but thanks

Comment: Then your options are 1. lock the width of your container, or 2. Use Oki Erie Rinaldi's solution and employ absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

What can i do is customize your css :

```
#center{
    background-color: green;
    position : absolute;
    width : 100%;
    z-index : -1;
}
```

`#center` fill all the empty space between it and `#right`. 
 but you have to notice it that the `#center` is behind the `#right`

Comment: Want to spare you a vote down: absolute positioning is an unnecessary compromise for this issue. See my answer or Mr Alien's.

Comment: yes, the result of your script is neater than mine. my result still have a little space at the edge of `#right`. I'm sorry about that.. :D

Comment: It's not the space, it's that absolute positioning comes at a price, it didn't seem necessary for this issue. That said, the OP isn't able to alter the DOM, so it may be an option after all.

Comment: using your code if i have a long text inside div id=center, there were some text that will not show up (because div id=center its behind div id=right). and as you say, the result still have a little space at the edge of #right. so i can't accept it as right answer. but thanks it was a nice trick